# How to access network file?

Tags: c++, windows

```
using namespace std;

ofstream myfile;
//myfile.open ("Z:\\ABC.TXT");                 // fails Z: is a network drive
//myfile.open("C:\\Temp\\ABC.TXT");            // OK
//myfile.open("Z:\\NETWORK\\02-010E.CHS");     // fails Z:\Network is a network folder

if (myfile.is_open())
    cout << "file is open" << endl;
else
    cout << "file fails to open" << endl;

myfile.close();
```

Question: It seems that `ofstream.open` doesn't support to open a file on a network drive.
Is there a simply way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::strerror(errno)` and see what it prints ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror)).

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
  using namespace std;

  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("\\\\servername\\filepath\\filename"); 
              //^^should follow this format, servername is not Z drive name

  if (myfile.is_open())
     cout << "file is open" << endl;
 else
     cout << "file fails to open" << endl;

 myfile.close();
```

I tried this to open a file on a shared server, it outputs

```
file is open
```

so it should work.

The `Z` drive is actually not real physical drive, it is just a mapping to real physical drive on the server.

Comment: Generally the mapped drives are per user, which might have been the problem.