# how to correctly write path for files in the network for c++11 fstream

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream

i need to open file that is in the network but my ifstream couldnt find the file.

when i rightclick --> properties the file the file location said is

```
\\LAPTOP-UDC1U1DT\Users\Public\Documents\log.txt
```

but this doesn't work in ifstream because of compiler errors.

```
\\\\server\\share\log.txt
```

i then tried this as said in another question, although this has no errors but the program couldn't find the file.

can somebody teach me how to correctly write the path for c++ so that fstream can find the file?

the text file by the way is shared using ad hoc.
thank you.

Comment: `\\` before l must be escaped too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access network file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023780/how-to-access-network-file)

Comment: what do you mean @AlexeyGuseynov ? can you correct my path?

Comment: You didn't escape the last back-slash.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo indeed i have read that one,. may ask how do i know the server name? is it the same for the loptopname?

Comment: A long time ago somebody decided to be not like others and used wrong slash for delimiting filenames. Usually `/` is used to delimit filenames and \ is a special symbol. If you write for windows you have to escape \ with \ to force compiler to treat it as usual symbol.

Comment: Try with forward slashes `"//server/share/log.txt"` or using raw strings: `R"(\\server\share\log.txt)"`

Comment: @Galik i tried  escapeing still no luck

Comment: @galik i tried the forward slash too, still couldnt it.

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov i edited it and still didnt work sadly

Comment: i think i misataken in the names of the folder .... how can i know the server name? how do i know that it is in share? the clues that i have is the path that it is written in the properties

Comment: Doesn't it tell you the path in the file browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open or read/write to a file in C++, you have got to use a double backslash instead of a single one. Moreover you have to use the full path because it may happen that your file is not located in the same directory as your .exe is.

Maybe try something like this:

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\text.txt", ios::in);
```

This should also work if you want to get a file out of your server which is your running system is connected to.

Comment: there is no drive letter , because the file is not in my system.

Comment: Then try to use the first format of directory in your question but use for every single backslash a double backslash. Should look like this (4 backslashes for the server): \\\\LAPTOP-UDC1U1DT\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\log.txt